# Handling a sword blade (directly) to stab

Tags: internal-consistency, weapons, tactics

I'm ESL, hope I can deliver the questions clearly.

Consider a regular and sharp longsword.

1. Would it be possible to stab someone by handling it close to the tip or maybe in the middle of the blade? (I never had one in my hands, I have no idea if you have enough stability to stab).
2. How much damage would it do to the hand?

Comment: There is no danger in grasping the middle of the sword, the sharp blade only cuts things sliding on it.

Comment: ESL maybe, but "stability to stab" is a pun you should be proud of.

Comment: @skout I find that unlikely. While it definitely cuts sliding things _better_, it's entirely possible to cut your finger while chopping vegetables; knives don't magically stop working until they're moved in a certain direction. Also, what are the odds that you're going to grasp something and have it not slide even a little? Of course, the cutting doesn't matter at all if the middle of your sword is duller than the tip, as the answers below suggest.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you mean to describe stabbing someone with the sword held *only* by the blade, or with the hilt and *also* the blade?

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it. That being said, I see this as being an issue of tactics, which we have a specific [tag:tactics] tag for and would advise [edit]ing into the question.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is about worldbuilding. It's more a practical combat question about real life weapons.

Comment: @NicHartley, most swords aren't especially sharp (especially considering how they are bashed against things). They were designed for beating and, to some extent, stabbing. Sharpened edges tended to be more for slashing weapons, like scimitars or cavalry swords. A typical medieval sword is for breaking bones as much as anything else.

Comment: I'll try to add the tag.

Comment: @flith That's fair; in that case the second half of my comment applies. I still don't think "your hand won't get cut _because it's not sliding_" is valid, though it doesn't really matter.

Comment: How is this about building a fictional world? This seems like a question about how a character wields a sword.

Answer (score 45):

The answer is Yes, of course, a warrior can grasp his own sword by the blade, and the old fighting manuals show this technique clearly (half-sword technique). 
There are also instances where it is recommended to grasp the opponent's sword.

[*Here*](https://thehemaists.com/2015/05/18/what-are-we-really-seeing-with-the-half-sword-images-of-talhoffer/) is good treatise on the topic of half-sword technique, when it's used & why.

From *Medieval Combat* (a translation & description of Talhoffer's *Fechbuch*), we read: "The half=sword techniques were originally devised for fighting armoured opponents. The sword is gripped on the blade with the left hand and used like a short spear or bayonet to slice or stab into the armpits, groin, face, throat and joints."

Even though the technique was devised for armoured fighting, it could certainly be used for fighting without armour. Apropos to the question of injury to the swordsman's hand, note that medieval guantlets did *not* fully encase the hand and fingers:

[image: Gauntlet]

The swordsman still had to wear a (thin) leathern glove underneath. This does not invalidate the answer, because the leather itself is relatively thin and offers little protection from stabs and slices. Thin leather = less bunching & greater range of motion; thick leather = bunching & less range of motion. You still need to take care in order not to slice your hand through the glove!

[Zweihander Techniques Demonstration](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DbNL_At0IVw)

[image][image][image]

Comment: Why on earth is he stabbing a naked women in that picture?

Comment: @DonQuiKong: because she has a sword and started the fight?  IDK, looks super-weird to me, too.  Maybe someone in the 1500s was looking for an excuse to draw boobs.

Comment: Without your hand protected, there is no way your hand is coming away from this unscathed. So... I feel these techniques may work once until your hand heals. So to the OPs question of 'how much damage it will do to the hand'... it will cut it up pretty good (force of stabbing someone WILL cause at least slight sliding of the blade, also squeezing the blade hard enough is sufficient to have it cut into the skin).

Comment: @TylerDahle Mordhau was intented for use in full armor, so you would have chainmail or something along those lines protecting your hand.

Comment: The first image in this answer seems to be doing that, and should be Ok. It is just the other two are bare-handedly grabbing the sword. And OP was looking at damage done to the hand. Yes, if protected with an armored gauntlet, your hand should be fine, but if just grabbing it bare-handed....

Comment: In the third picture, it looks like the left fighter grabbed the sword to redirect it away from his body and/or pull his opponent closer as he stabs his opponent -- for the former, a sliced hand is a vastly preferable outcome versus a stabbed torso, and for the latter, taking lacerations to the hand to ensure a victorious outcome is preferable to continuing to fight with a less certain outcome.

Comment: @DonQuiKong I like how unhappy she is about it, too.  Look at that frown.  Clearly, getting stabbed in the boob is a sub-optimal morning.

Comment: Having practiced with sharp one-and-a-half hand swords for a good while I can say that the half-blade technique depicted in the first and second images can be _safely_ executed without any hand protection.

Comment: The swords in the 3rd picture appear to be edgeless, like an epee. If so, grabbing the blade is not an issue.

Comment: @DonQuiKong  Apparently we don't know.  It appears to be from a from a 1400's fencing manual that wasn't finished.  http://wiktenauer.com/wiki/Wolfenb%C3%BCttel_Sketchbook_(Cod.Guelf.78.2_Aug.2%C2%BA)

Comment: @DonQuiKong I vaguely recall that that was believed to be a judicial duel. The woman would have been accused of adultery. If she can win the swordfight, she can go free, but given the magnitude of her crime (ugh) she has to fight unarmored and naked.

There's probably details I'm forgetting.

Comment: Anyone else think of arrow season 3 episode 9 when they saw the third picture?

Comment: @TylerDahle : Nope. You won't cut you hand. And Nikola Stojanovic, no, there was nothing more than maybe leather on your palms. And  there is no such thing as "chainmail". Here is a video demonstrating the technique without gloves and with a sharp sword: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwuQPfvSSlo

Comment: @TylerDahle : correct; notice the way he's gripping the blade. He's not just grabbing it like a broom, he's got the flat of the blade on his thenar and is locking it with the pads of his fingers. Blade's not going anywhere.

Comment: While interesting, I don't find this answer convincing enough. In the two first images the hand in the grip must be doing lots of force when compared to the hand in the blade, so it is not really the same that the OP is asking. In the third picture the objective is to block/restrict the sword, not to stab.

Comment: @SJuan76 : I'm not sure how period illustrations of the technique and modern video fail to convince! I'll add some relevant text which will hopefully be an improvement. Also, the OP asks "Handling a sword blade (directly) to stab" which is exactly what is depicted.

Comment: As I undertand it, the OP is asking about stabbing someone while handling the sword **only with one hand**, not with both. That could make for a lot of difference in the amount of pressure need to be made by the hand.

Comment: I see. Well, the OP can clarify that. I don't see where he's asking about gripping the blade "only with one hand" (and not holding any other part of the sword). The physics of that would make the manoeuvre unwieldy at best. 70+cm of steel blade, plus heavy hilts & pommel flapping about uncontrolled doesn't seem like what's being asked!

Answer (score 30):

Yes, it's possible to stab someone by holding the middle of the blade.

As a weapon, the long sword was often used with half-swording techniques; so often, the other hand would be holding the blade.

**Half Swording** was a thing back in the day, where people would grab the middle of their blade with their hands while using the sword. The sharpest part of a sword is often closer to the tip, so this was relatively safe as long as you were wearing some sort of hand protection (eg: Plate gauntlet/ Thick leather gloves/ etc.). Even without the hand protection, it is theoretically possible to grip the blade such that your palm and fingers would not be sliced open.

This actually allowed the sword to be "shortened" for **more powerful** thrusts, or have more leverage when in close quarters.

Also often done was the flipping around of the sword to use the handle side as a mace/war hammer type implement.

Comment: We should keep in mind, though, that half-swording relies on one hand holding the hilt.

Comment: @Alexander You'd be surprised, that wasn't always the case. There are stories of some fighters using both hands on the blade when swinging with the hilt out

Comment: But that still requires two hands, with one placed at the hilt end.

Comment: @Alexander and either wearing gloves or having one hand on the hilt and the other holding the sword *lower* than half way down.

Comment: "The sharpest part of a sword is often closer to the tip" really, the whole sword is sharp... but pressure against the blade isn't what cuts you. It is motion on it. So if you hold it tight so it doesn't slide across your skin, you can hold it at any point on the length of the blade with bare hands fairly safely. Of course, I'd still prefer to be wearing some gloves when attempting, especially since thrusting it into someone makes it liable to slide in your hand too!

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe medieval swords weren't all that sharp.

Comment: @Aify `fighters using both hands on the blade when swinging with the hilt out`, yes, the "murder blow" - but that's not a stab. I'm still not sure if the OP means to ask if you could stab someone holding *only* the blade, or *also* the blade.

Comment: @Erik people think medieval swords are giant kitchen knives.  They're not even close.  Even a modern machete is not remotely as sharp as a typical kitchen knife.  At high sharpness, you lose a lot of durability.  A machete that's sharpened is much more useful than a blunt one, but it is nowhere near the sharpness of a typical kitchen knife.

Comment: @Aify *As a weapon, the longsword was never just held by the handle* - care to clarify? The obvious reading of this is clearly wrong, and the rest of your answer implies enough knowledge of the subject to know better.

Comment: @Erik that's a myth. I'm sure there were variations in build, maintenance, and some made for other uses where durability matters more than sharpness (as the case of the machete, or a sword primarily made for thusting), but generally speaking, the medieval sword was a weapon of violence and writings from the time talk of cutting and slicing with them. If you are going to cutting and slicing with the intent to kill, sharpness is implied. And if it can cut your enemy, it can cut your own flesh too if not used properly. BUT, half-swording, when done correctly, can be done with a sharp blade!

Comment: @AdamD.Ruppe 'used incorrectly' is the key bit here.  Quite a few swords, ancient and otherwise, are not very sharp by most people's definition.  Pretty much anything bigger than a short sword does most of it's damage because of momentum, not sharpness.  Bastard swords and two-handers are probably the best example, as they were largely designed solely for slashing and thus usually have somewhat dull edges with a very high angle of grind, relying on momentum to cleave a for instead of a sharp edge.

Comment: "As a weapon, the longsword was never just held by the handle." Citation needed, because this is incorrect.

Comment: @walrus I mean that also having a hand on the blade (eg: halfswording) was very common. I'll edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: @Erik look at kreigmeisers and falchions,  both of witch are insanely sharp, they galen to be the best cutting swords ever. The only sword that could bot cut wad an estoc sword as they are designed to punch thru armour and  we're discussing engineered for stiffness, they have a trefoil blade and thus have no true edge.

Answer (score 9):

With a sharp-edged longsword (no [ricasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricasso) , no gauntlets and no cheating by holding sword's hilt with the other hand), not so much damage.

Skin will be punctured, and an eye can be lost, but there can be no deep penetration, because the attacker's hand's grip will slip over the sharp edge. That hand can be cut to the bone, if attacker is trying hard.

- Attacker can practice a grip over blade sides only, avoiding sharp edges. This way, apparently, more damage can be done, but this grip would require a lot of practice and still remain much weaker than a normal hilt grip.
- Another way or dealing substantial damage is using sufficient space when thrusting the sword to let the sword gain momentum. This way it is not much the grip, but the sword's own weight that would deal the damage.

Two techniques above would be sufficient to kill an unarmored opponent, but still not likely to be effective even against a light (like leather) armor.

Comment: Thanks to all answers, I was surprised on how fast the answers came. I think I'm alright with the answers so far. Just to give a better context, I'm writing a scene where the MC is being punched on the ground, swallowing lots of water and can't have a good grasp on his sword to react. The opponent is unarmored. It is a climax scene, and he grabs the sword to stab. And there goes my questions. From what you guys are writing, I get it won't be terribly effective, but it is not impossible to work. I'm good with that and I will keep that on my scene. You guys saved the day!

Comment: @SilvaFilho Efficiency would depend on the sword and if the MC has gauntlets or such. A gauntleted hand on a proper ricasso wide enough for a hold is much better than a bare hand on a blade. That said, wounded hand is rarely lethal and has a decent chance of healing.

Comment: You're not wrong, but the danger of using a sword at the blade can be overestimated. There are videos of people performing full-powered murder strokes (both hands holding the edge striking with the hilt/pommel) with bare hands and a sharp longsword without any injury (e.g. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vwuQPfvSSlo)

Comment: @Pahlavan using sword as a hammer... interesting, I have not considered that option.

Comment: @Alexander It's a technique for fighting in heavy armour - using the pommel to strike against a helmet can be more effective than the blade as it imparts more force (since the hilt is heavier than the blade) and you can't cut through steel plate - apparently striking with the point of the crossguard can also work, since it concentrates the force. Furthermore you can use the crossguard to hook around a limb (most commonly a leg to pull the opponent off their feet).

Comment: @Pahlavan Yeah, now that I think of it, using both hands would help a lot with hand safety. And hitting with the pommel even more as you'd get the force with the hand against the ricasso or guard and the hand on the blade would only need to grip the flat not around the edges.

Comment: @VilleNiemi You hit the key point there: you have to grip the blade by applying pressure to the flats with a bit of distance to the edge (if possible) and take care not to let your hands slide up/down - it's the sliding over the edge that cuts; just touching it, even with some pressure, won't hurt you.

Comment: @SilvaFilho The obvious question there: what happened to the MC's dagger?  In a medieval context, even just in everyday life, you'd be about as likely to go out without a knife as to go out naked, and that's just for wandering around town.  *Everyone* wore a knife, all the time, even if they'd mostly just use it as a hand tool.  In any kind of military context though, that'd be a proper dagger for exactly this kind of situation, which is why all modern soldiers still carry a fighting knife.  (And the next question of course is why the opponent is punching him instead of stabbing him.)

Comment: @Graham he is without his daggers (he was being kept locked) and he had so much confidence in his superior ability that he didn't mind pursuing the other man with 'only' a sword. The guy he is fighting is not a warrior.

Comment: @SilvaFilho Fair enough, but you do have another problem - you need to explain why the guy he's fighting isn't stabbing him.  And they really *all* carried knives, all the time, even children.  Even if it was only a small knife intended more for eating, it's still a weapon.

Comment: @Graham good point. I'll propably translate the scene here (it isn't big and it is fast paced). The antagonist gets killed and I show that he had his knives with him. He decide not to use them. He needed thr MC alive for 'magic' reasons (to inherit a magical artifact, that must be passed by the owner). Or simply he didn't want to kill. I'll leave that for the readers to figure out.

Answer (score 5):

[image]

I've actually had this problem in real life before.
Couldn't explain it well without drawing it.

I pushed the butt of my hands together along the face of the blade while locking fingers over the blunt end of the blade.

Of course this method won't work with 2-sided blades

I used this method as I had snapped the hilt of my sword off

Answer (score 3):

The other answers discuss the technique quite well, so I wanted to toss this in.

According to http://www.darksword-armory.com/how-sharp-were-medieval-swords/, The relative sharpness of the longsword varied across time. If the blade was destined to attack an unarmored or leather clad warrior, it's edge would have been sharper (also more brittle). In this era, we would assume half-sword techniques without any sort of hand protection to be potentially catastrophic to the hand.

However, with the advent of chain mail and plate armor, razor sharp edges became less desirable. Less razor-like equals less damage to the bare hand.

Depending on your time period (and ultimate sword design), your character could lose a finger or two from the trauma. On the other hand, the sword may not even be sharpened up to a point, if it's intended target is plate-clad. Minimal/no damage could be possible.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible, it's called half-swording and it's quite common in a good amount of longsword manuals.
With a proper way of gripping the sword you can half-sword safely even without a pair of gloves and sustain no damage to your hands. Skallagrim has a video in which he does exactly [that](https://youtu.be/vwuQPfvSSlo?t=2m18s), half-swording with his bare hands then Mordhau-ing a rubber tire, although he admits that wearing gloves give a psychological advantage to half-swording.

Comment: +1 because I love Skallagrim, but I'd suggest you comment a bit on what happens in the video and give a description of the techniques used (also in case - heavens forbid - his channel gets deleted for some reason)

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with one hand on the blade and the other on the hilt (aka Half-swording), but doing with with both hands on the blade would not work. You would not have enough grip to hold the blade firmly and it would just slip off your hands. That's why cross-guards were made, so you can have a point of contact when you thrust. That part gives superior grip and prevents the hand from slipping on the blade.

Even if you had a good grip, the damage would be superficial, you would only "scratch" your opponent, no serious injury. In fact, you might hurt yourself more than you hurt your opponent if you lack hand protection.

Comment: That's only part of why cross guards originated. They also serve to catch an opponents blocked sword as it slides down the blade.

Comment: @hawker65 what if you could keep applying pressure against the opponent's torso (clothes + skin only), would it be possible for the blade to slide in?

Comment: @Austin Hemmelgarn True, but it's very situational.

Comment: You could stab him, but the wound would be mostly superficial and mainly due to the speed of the blade. Once you actually hit the person with the blade, your hands would probably slide off. If you mean that you wouldn't lose grip, in that case you could stab the person "normally", but would would probably lose some power because of the awkward gripping of the blade.